# When drawing three number from the same distribution, what is the probability of the first to be between the two?

Tags: probability, distributions

If I draw 3 numbers: $a$, $b$ and $c$ from the exact same distribution (unknown, but the same for each of the numbers).
I want to know the probability that $a$ is between $b$ and $c$.
That is: $b < a < c$ or $c < a < b$.

Naturally, I expect the probability to be $\frac{1}{3}$.
This is because it is easy to prove that for uniform distribution it is true, and we can simulate any distribution using a uniform one.

Can this be proven formally?

Comment: Without loss of generality, let us assume you are drawing $a$, $b$, and $c$ from a set of positive integers denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_+$. Assuming that $a \ne b \ne c$, then you have six possible combinations. Clearly, if $a$ has to lie between $b$ and $c$, there are only two possibilities out of the six, therefore the probability is 1/3.

Comment: Well, you can prove it for uniform, and then you can generate any other distribution from uniform by a *monotone non-decreasing* transformation (the quantile transfromation). Will such a transformation change any probabilities?

Comment: A pretty standard homework question in probability. How does this problem arise?

Comment: @Glen_b I'm actually about to submit a conference paper and I assumed it is true. But I suddenly doubt my self so I wanted to verify that.

Comment: Thanks. It's a simple counting argument; for a continuous distribution there are $3!=6$ possible orders, which are by symmetry equally probable $(abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba)$, of which two have $a$ in the middle. If you don't have continuous distributions you have to worry about ties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the three can be the one in the middle. If you think it may be more probable that $a$ is the one in the middle than $b,$ then what happens if you rename them so that the one called $a$ is then called $b$ and vice-versa? Does $b$ then become the more probable one?

If they're independent and the distribution is continuous, then the probability of a tie is $0.$ If the distribution is continuous and they're not assumed independent, then there is nothing in the way you stated the problem to prevent the first and second outcomes to be equal ALWAYS.

If they're not independent and the distribution is discrete, then it can still happen that the probability of two being equal is zero and each has probability $1/3$ of being the one in the middle. As follows: Choose WITHOUT REPLACEMENT from the set $\{1,2,3\}.$

As long as the distribution of the three random variables is *exchangeable* and the probability of a tie is $0,$ then the three have equal probability of being the one in the middle.